# Remove all the lines that contain`a' in a file and write it to another file

Tags: python, file

The python program is to remove all the lines that contain the character `a' in a file
I can replace the a's but how can i remove complete lines in the file

```
fo=open("hp.txt","w")
fo.write("Harry Potter")
fo.write("There is a difference in all harry potter books\nWe can see it as harry grows\nthe books were written by J.K rowling ")
fo.close()

fo=open('hp.txt','r')
fi=open('writehp.txt','w')
l=fo.readlines()
for i in l:
    if 'a' in i:
        i=i.replace('a','')
        fi.write(i)
fi.close()
fo.close()
```

-File body

--File hp

Harry PotterThere is a difference in all harry potter books

We can see it as harry grows

the books were written by J.K rowling

--File hpwrite

Hrry PotterThere us  difference in ll hrry potter books

lthough I cn gree the books re lwys

better thn the movies

Comment: In your own words, what are you expecting `i=i.replace('a','') and fi.write(i)` to do?

Comment: Yes I forgot to remove the 'and'  as i had just changed it in the code as a last resort thankyou for your help

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is that you first use `.readline()` (It will read only one line) but you need `.readlines()` to get list of all lines, then `i=i.replace('a','') and fi.write(i)` is faulty:

```
fo=open("hp.txt","w")
fo.write("Harry Potter")
fo.write("There is a difference in all harry potter books\nWe can see it as harry grows\nthe books were written by J.K rowling ")
fo.close()

fo=open('hp.txt','r')
fi=open('writehp.txt','w')
l=fo.readlines()
for i in l:
    if 'a' in i:
        i=i.replace('a','')
        fi.write(i)
fi.close()
fo.close()
```